# Making an object move in a random direction in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an `EnemyTest` gameobject that, through an `EnemyDmg` script, instantiates a damage number whenever a weapon hits it. I would like to put a script on the damage number prefab that will make it move in a random direction in 2-dimensional space. I know other people have asked this, but the thing is, I would like to be able to move the damage number without rotating it, so that it can still be easily read. I am planning on putting the code for the damage number movement in a new script on the prefab, contained within a `void Awake()` method.

This is the EnemyDmg script:

```cs
public class EnemyDmg : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject EnemyCanvas;
    public GameObject DmgNmbr;

    void Start()
    {
        EnemyCanvas = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Collider)
    {
        if (Collider.gameObject.tag == "Weapon")
        {
            Debug.Log("Enemy Hit!");
            Instantiate(DmgNmbr, EnemyCanvas.transform);
        }
    }
}
```

As it currently is, this is what happens when a weapon hits the enemy: [Google Drive Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11sCcXzythDh1hQFkBGHE7l7NoDfcl3t3/view?usp=sharing). I would like the yellow number to fly off of the enemy in a random direction, although it doesn't have to go very far. From this perspective, the x-axis is left and right, and the y-axis is up and down.

Comment: The question does not explain what direction is the front of the sprite or what axis it should rotate around. Please include a picture showing the local axes of the enemy gameobject. [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/SpriteFrom3DViewPt.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1446119/moving-a-non-player-object-in-a-random-direction-w.html

In that link someone has given a recipe for moving an object in a random direction. However, I could not understand what exactly you do ask.

```
private Vector3 RandomVector(float min, float max) {
     var x = Random.Range(min, max);
     var y = Random.Range(min, max);
     var z = Random.Range(min, max);
     return new Vector3(x, y, z);
 }

 void Start()
 { 
     var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
     rb.velocity = RandomVector(0f, 5f);
 }
```

Comment: I used this code and tweaked it just a little bit for what I need it for. Once I made the changes, it worked exactly the way I wanted it too. Thanks!